# HTML Checkbox does not changes after forms get away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, checkbox

i have a form which comes on `button` click shows and hides on clicking on close button.
in the form i have a html Checkbox and when i ticked the `checkbox` and close the form and open again on `button` click the `checkbox` still remain the same which i don't want it should get unticketd(false) as soon as the form hides.
**.aspx code**

```
</div>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="Checkboxemail" id="ChkEmail"  style="margin-right: 9px;"  value="FALSE" />I wish to be contacted regarding my feedback</label>
 </div>

 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close-feedback" onclick="FeedBackClose();"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>

    function FeedBackClose() {
                debugger;
                $("#commentTextArea").val("");
                $("#TopicSelect").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
                $(".rating input:radio").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#<%= TenantMaster_FeedbackSubmitButton.ClientID %>").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#TopicSelect").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#commentTextArea").removeAttr('disabled');
                $(".rating input:radio").removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#TopicSelect').parents(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                $('#commentTextArea').parents(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
                $(".close-feedback").show();
                        $("div.slideFeedback").show().stop().animate({
                            "top": "-100%"
                        }, 2000);
                         $("html, body").removeClass("hide-body-scroll");
                         $("#wrapper").css("overflow", "auto");
                           $(".mask").remove();
            };
```

**form UI screenshot**.
  [image]

Comment: You should set up the `value` attribute dynamically. Right now, it is always `FALSE`.

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: in close event.

Comment: please provide html

Comment: If you want it to be false every time the form shows, then juste reset the `value` attribute each time the user click the button. Ie (with jQuery):  `$('#myButton').on('click', function () { $('#ChkEmail').val(false); $('#myForm').show() });`

Comment: The code that matters is the code that opens the form. But I don't see it.

Comment: added @Roamer-1888

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Close` event you can add this Code to set up the `value` attribute

```
var res =  document.getElementById("ChkEmail");

  res.value = false;
```

Or

```
var res = document.getElementById("ChkEmail");

   res.checked= false;
```